# ionViewWillEnter vs ionViewDidEnter

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When we would not want to reinitiate a task that is already cache, there is no doubt that we will be using `ionDidLoad`.

Now, let's make assumption that we need to do a task each and every time when we are entering a view, how do we choose between using `ionViewWillEnter` vs `ionViewDidEnter`.

I did not find any clear guideline on this.

For example: 
1) Getting navParams 
2) Calling REST api 
3) Declaring variable 
4) Initiate something after DOM element loaded completely (eg: google map init)

**Additional note:** 
I am note looking for an answer that is clearly written in the ionic documentation. What am I intend to know is what is the pros and cons if put in `ionViewWillEnter` vs  `ionViewDidEnter`

eg: Initiating in `ionViewDidEnter` will cause some delay (for example, i am not sure about this) - even the insignificant one

Comment: Please refer this link. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: ^ This link is dead @hrdkisback

Comment: Updated link https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

sebaferreras [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414906/4254681) is great but it is missing some points.
 First, about [ionic life cycle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events). If you write down all ionic events and put a `console.log` in each, you will see the scenario:

```
constructor --> ionViewDidLoad --> ionViewWillEnter --> ionViewDidEnter --> ionViewWillLeave --> ionViewDidLeave --> ionViewWillUnload.
```

`constructor` run first when the page is initiated. This is the best place for you to declare default values for your variables.
`ionViewDidLoad` is fired when the view is completely loaded. It means you can attach DOM element here. 
`ionViewWillEnter` runs when the page is **about to enter** and become the active page.
`ionViewDidEnter` runs when the page has **fully entered** and is now the active page.
`ionViewDidEnter` will fire after **all** **synchronous** in `ionViewWillEnter` completed. To prove it, just put heavy code into `ionViewWillEnter`:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log("ionViewWillEnter")
    for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
      console.log(i);
    }
}
ionViewDidEnter(){
    console.log("ionViewDidEnter")
}
```

Run your code and you will see it take so long time to launch your page. So never put heavy **synchronous** code into  `ionViewWillEnter`. Just use **asynchronous** in `ionViewWillEnter` and move all **synchronous** code to `ionViewDidEnter`. Because in there, your page is entered and it will make a better UX.

Comment: _Just use asynchronous in `ionViewWillEnter` and move all synchronous code to `ionViewDidEnter`_ Great answer, thanks for bringing that out :)

Comment: Except for the last paragraph, this is a Microsoft Help type answer - just state the obvious and expand the name of the item. :-)

Answer (score 9):

The answer is quite simple and, as always, the best way to see what's going on behind the scenes is to inspect the source code of Ionic.

Long story short: **the `ionViewWillEnter` lifecycle hook is triggered before the page transition begins, and the `ionViewDidEnter` is triggered after the transition finishes**. Please take a look at the end of this answer to see the reference to the source code.

So, when you should use each of these hooks? There must be several possible scenarios, so these are only a few ideas based on some applications I've worked on.

- Sometimes you want to update some information on the page every time the user opens that page; that may require making an HTTP request to a remote API to fetch some data. In that case, we could say that using the `IonViewWillEnter` seems like the right option, so you can make the request as soon as possible, obtaining the response sooner as well.
- The same applies when you need to interact with the DOM for some reason because the DOM has been already loaded when the `IonViewWillEnter` is executed, so this could help you to initialize the page as soon as possible, and with a little bit of luck the page could be shown to the user *ready to be used*.
- The same is valid when you need to initialize the view with some parameters that you get from the previous view. In this case, since it's a very simple operation, you can use the `ionViewWillEnter` lifecycle hook and the view will be shown already initialized to the user.

So when should you use the `ionViewDidEnter` then?

- I've noticed that sometimes when executing the app on very old android devices (with less than 512mb - 1gb RAM), the animation can be a little bit lagged when making a request to the API in the `ionViewWillEnter`, so it'd be a good idea to make these requests to the API in the `ionViewDidEnter` to make sure that the animation is finished
- In some apps I've been asked to include some fancy animations to the elements of the pushed page, like bringing part of the content from the bottom, fading some other elements after a delay, and so on. You could use angular animations for that (in order to be able to have control over the timing), and the best way to avoid some lag on these animations would be to use the `ionViewDidEnter` hook. This also will allow you to make the user feel like the animations of the elements within that page are a continuation of the transition of the page itself.

---

You can take a look at the **[NavControllerBase code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/navigation/nav-controller-base.ts)**:

### **1) `IonViewWillEnter`**

```
// around line 666...
_transitionStart(...): Promise<NavResult> {

    // ...

    // around line 700...

    // create a callback that needs to run within zone
    // that will fire off the willEnter/Leave lifecycle events at the right time
    transition.beforeAddRead(this._viewsWillLifecycles.bind(this, enteringView, leavingView));

   // ...

}
```

And...

```
  // around line 805...
  _viewsWillLifecycles(enteringView: ViewController, leavingView: ViewController) {
    if (enteringView || leavingView) {
      this._zone.run(() => {
        // Here, the order is important. WillLeave must be called before WillEnter.
        leavingView && this._willLeave(leavingView, !enteringView);
        enteringView && this._willEnter(enteringView);
      });
    }
  }
```

If you inspect the `beforeAddRead` method from the `animation.d.ts` definition you'll see:

```
/**
* Add a function which contains DOM reads, which will run
* before the animation begins.
*/
beforeAddRead(domReadFn: Function): Animation;
```

So now we can be sure that the `ionViewWillEnter` lifecycle hook is executed **before the page transition begins**

### **2) `IonViewDidEnter`**

This one is a little bit simpler. Again in the same `NavControllerBase`:

```
// around line 743...
  _transitionFinish(...): NavResult {

    // ...

    // around line 753...
    if (hasCompleted) {
      // transition has completed (went from 0 to 1)
      if (enteringView) {
        enteringName = enteringView.name;
        this._didEnter(enteringView);
      }

      // ..

    }

    // ...

  }
```

And

```
// around line 939...
  _didEnter(view: ViewController) {
    assert(this.isTransitioning(), 'nav controller should be transitioning');
    assert(NgZone.isInAngularZone(), 'callback should be zoned');

    try {
      view._didEnter();
      this.viewDidEnter.emit(view);
      this._app.viewDidEnter.emit(view);
    } catch (e) {
      this._errHandler && this._errHandler.handleError(e);
    }
  }
```

So because of that, we can say that **the `ionViewDidEnter`lifecycle hook is triggered after the transition finishes.**

Comment: You did a harder way(i.e. investigation the `codebase`) when compared it with `Duannx` answer.But we always like to have a different solution for the same question. `Upvoted`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the task before view will appear then use **ionViewWillEnter**.
If you want to do the task after view appears then use **ionViewDidEnter**.

It totally depends on the scenario. For example, If you want to change the properties of ui element before the view is displayed you use ionViewWillEnter. In your question's examples: 4) Initiate something after DOM element loaded completely (eg: google map init. So here in this scenario you can use ionViewDidEnter

Comment: yes. it's pretty clear in word but ambiguous in choice of implementation. "If you want". Technically, there should be a pros and cons of implementing my above example in `ionViewWillEnter` vs `ionViewDidEnter`.  eg: will there be a lagging if i initiate it after view enter or vice versa. I am looking for some justification like this. Even it is of slightest difference.

Comment: It totally depends on the scenario. For example, If you want to change the properties of ui element before the view is displayed you use ionViewWillEnter. In your question's examples: 4) Initiate something after DOM element loaded completely (eg: google map init. So here in this scenario you can use ionViewDidEnter